# How to find element in selenium python using class in div with different selection

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath( "//div[@class='pepDayScroller_dayNum']").click()
```

for below elements but it did not work. Please help.

Try to located second element with a number of 2

```html
<div class="pepDayScroller_dayNum">1</div>
<div class="pepDayScroller_dayNum">2</div>
<div class="pepDayScroller_dayNum">3</div>
```

here is addition information

```js
<div class="pepDayScroller_dayWrapper">
  <a href="#" class="pepDayScroller_day pepDayScroller_day--selected" data-index="0">
    <div class="accessibleText accessibleSelectedMark" aria-hidden="false">Selected</div>
    <div class="pepDayScroller_dayNum">1</div>
    <div class="pepDayScroller_startingFrom"><div 
      class="pepDayScroller_startingFromLabel">Prices vary by date.</div>
    </div>
   </a>
  </div>
```

```html
<div class="pepDayScroller_dayWrapper"><a href="#" class="pepDayScroller_day pepDayScroller_day--selected" data-index="0"><div class="accessibleText accessibleSelectedMark" aria-hidden="false">Selected</div><div class="pepDayScroller_dayNum">1</div><div class="pepDayScroller_startingFrom"><div class="pepDayScroller_startingFromLabel">Prices vary by date.</div></div></a></div>
```

once I am able to click on this button, it will scroll down and ask me to select either it is peak or value. codes are below

```html
<a href="#" class="pepTieredCalendar_dateBox tappable pepTieredCalendar_dateBox--32 pepTieredCalendar_dateBox--value" tabindex="0" role="button" data-tier="value" data-date="2018-09-27" aria-label="2018-09-27, 87.30 USD">
                    <span class="pepTieredCalendar_dateBoxText">27</span>
                </a>
```

how do I find these elements.thanks

Answer (score 2):

The class which you're trying to refer matches many elements at once. You could try to find by matching text like:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '2')]")`

or by matching all elements and selecting the one that you need:

```py
all_elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pepDayScroller_dayNum")
two_element = None

for el in all_elements:
    if el.text == "2":
        two_element = el
        break
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: It seems work. however, it turns out more problem. it is unable to use .click(). error pop up like this: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click';   sorry, i should have  post the full code. i will re-post it.

Comment: You should post the code you have developed so far, not only the html you're trying to interact with.

Comment: the code i have so far is just use to open the websites. that actually is the first step

Comment: I edited the first suggestion I've given in my answer to you as it should have been `find_element_by_xpath` and not `find_elements_by_xpath `. That's probably the reason why you are getting the error if you're really using it.

Comment: the error pop up is because i added .click().  i need to click on it and then it will scroll down and give me another option to select. driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '1')]").click()

Comment: maybe your selection is returning more than one item or not the one that you really want. I urge you again to reformulate or edit your question with the actual code you're using, exactly what you are trying to accomplish, what has worked so far, what went wrong, what you have tried to do in order to solve it, etc. Until then It's very difficult to help you any further. Sorry...